# Привязка items с setOnClickListener к position

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, arraylist, recyclerviewadapter

В моём `RecyclerView` есть несколько `items` по нажатию на них с помощью `setOnClickListener` открывается `Fragmet`, но есть проблема, `items position` не привязано к `setOnClickListener position` то есть, допустим я сделал сортировку и позиция `item` поменялась а позиция `setOnClickListener` нет, и по нажатию на первый `item` всегда будет открываться один и тот же `Fragmet`. Как их связать? Как я понял в файле где у меня находятся атрибуты `item`, нужно присвоить какую-то переменную и ссылаться на неё в `setOnClickListener`, но это только догадка.

Сейчас у меня в `Adapter` поочерёдная смена позиций. Как её привязать к `item` находящиеся в `exampleList = new ArrayList<>();`?

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AttractionsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        AttractionsItem currentItem = mFavList.get(position);
        holder.card_image_1.setImageResource(currentItem.getImg1());
        holder.card_image_2.setImageResource(currentItem.getImg2());
        holder.card_text_1.setText(currentItem.get_attraction_name());
        holder.card_text_2.setText(currentItem.get_attraction_type());
        holder.card_text_3.setText(currentItem.get_attraction_cost());

        holder.Card.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            switch (position) {
                case 0: {
                    FragmentBabyIsland fragment = new FragmentBabyIsland(); // you fragment
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) v.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager(); // instantiate your view context
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.nav_default_enter_anim, R.animator.nav_default_exit_anim,
                            R.animator.nav_default_pop_enter_anim, R.animator.nav_default_pop_exit_anim);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment);// your container and your fragment
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("tag");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    break;
                }
                case 1: {
                    FragmentJumpAround fragment = new FragmentJumpAround(); // you fragment
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) v.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager(); // instantiate your view context
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.nav_default_enter_anim, R.animator.nav_default_exit_anim,
                            R.animator.nav_default_pop_enter_anim, R.animator.nav_default_pop_exit_anim);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment);// your container and your fragment
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("tag");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    FragmentMerryGoRound fragment = new FragmentMerryGoRound(); // you fragment
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) v.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager(); // instantiate your view context
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.nav_default_enter_anim, R.animator.nav_default_exit_anim,
                            R.animator.nav_default_pop_enter_anim, R.animator.nav_default_pop_exit_anim);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment);// your container and your fragment
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("tag");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    break;
                }
                case 3: {
                    FragmentFiveDCinema fragment = new FragmentFiveDCinema(); // you fragment
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) v.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager(); // instantiate your view context
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.nav_default_enter_anim, R.animator.nav_default_exit_anim,
                            R.animator.nav_default_pop_enter_anim, R.animator.nav_default_pop_exit_anim);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment);// your container and your fragment
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("tag");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

`Fragment` в котором расположен `RecyclerView`

```
public class FragmentAttractionRecyclerView extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mRec;
    private AttractionsAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<AttractionsItem> exampleList;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private String[]mArraysNames= new String[]{"Baby островок","Виражи","Вокруг света","5D кинотеатр"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attraction_test_2, container, false);

    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        createExampleList();
        buildRecyclerView();

        ImageView sort_alphabet = requireView().findViewById(R.id.sort_alphabet);

        sort_alphabet.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            sortArray();
            sortArrayList();
        });
    }

    private void sortArray(){
        Arrays.sort(mArraysNames);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    private void sortArrayList(){
        Collections.sort(exampleList, (o100, o200) -> o100.get_attraction_cost().compareTo(o200.get_attraction_cost()));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    public void createExampleList() {
        exampleList = new ArrayList<>();
        exampleList.add(new AttractionsItem(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_kid, "Baby островок", "Детский", "60₽"));
        exampleList.add(new AttractionsItem(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_kid, "Виражи", "Детский", "80₽"));
        exampleList.add(new AttractionsItem(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_kid, "Вокруг света", "Детский", "50₽"));
        exampleList.add(new AttractionsItem(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_interactive, "5D кинотеатр", "Интерактивный", "120₽"));
   }

    public void buildRecyclerView() {
        mRec = requireView().findViewById(R.id.attraction_recycler);
        adapter = new AttractionsAdapter(exampleList);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        mRec.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRec.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

`Adapter`

```
public class AttractionsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AttractionsAdapter.AttractionsViewHolder> {
    public ArrayList<AttractionsItem> mFavList;

    public AttractionsAdapter(ArrayList<AttractionsItem> favList) {
        mFavList = favList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AttractionsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_attraction, parent, false);
        AttractionsViewHolder evh = new AttractionsViewHolder(v);
        return evh;

    }

    public static class AttractionsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView card_image_1, card_image_2;
        public TextView card_text_1, card_text_2, card_text_3, attraction_menu_1_1, attraction_menu_1_2;
        public CardView Card;

        public AttractionsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            card_image_1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_image_1);
            card_image_2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_image_2);
            card_text_1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_text_1);
            card_text_2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_text_2);
            card_text_3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_text_3);
            attraction_menu_1_1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.attraction_menu_1_1);
            attraction_menu_1_2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.attraction_menu_1_2);
            Card = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Card);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AttractionsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        AttractionsItem currentItem = mFavList.get(position);
        holder.card_image_1.setImageResource(currentItem.getImg1());
        holder.card_image_2.setImageResource(currentItem.getImg2());
        holder.card_text_1.setText(currentItem.get_attraction_name());
        holder.card_text_2.setText(currentItem.get_attraction_type());
        holder.card_text_3.setText(currentItem.get_attraction_cost());

        holder.Card.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            switch (position) {
                case 0: {
                    FragmentBabyIsland fragment = new FragmentBabyIsland(); // you fragment
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) v.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager(); // instantiate your view context
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.nav_default_enter_anim, R.animator.nav_default_exit_anim,
                            R.animator.nav_default_pop_enter_anim, R.animator.nav_default_pop_exit_anim);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment);// your container and your fragment
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("tag");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    break;
                }
                case 1: {
                    FragmentJumpAround fragment = new FragmentJumpAround(); // you fragment
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) v.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager(); // instantiate your view context
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.nav_default_enter_anim, R.animator.nav_default_exit_anim,
                            R.animator.nav_default_pop_enter_anim, R.animator.nav_default_pop_exit_anim);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment);// your container and your fragment
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("tag");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    FragmentMerryGoRound fragment = new FragmentMerryGoRound(); // you fragment
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) v.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager(); // instantiate your view context
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.nav_default_enter_anim, R.animator.nav_default_exit_anim,
                            R.animator.nav_default_pop_enter_anim, R.animator.nav_default_pop_exit_anim);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment);// your container and your fragment
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("tag");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    break;
                }
                case 3: {
                    FragmentFiveDCinema fragment = new FragmentFiveDCinema(); // you fragment
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) v.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager(); // instantiate your view context
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.nav_default_enter_anim, R.animator.nav_default_exit_anim,
                            R.animator.nav_default_pop_enter_anim, R.animator.nav_default_pop_exit_anim);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment);// your container and your fragment
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("tag");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFavList.size();
    }
}
```

Наш `item`

```
public class AttractionsItem
{
    private int mImg_1,mImg_2;
    private final String mText_attraction_name;
    private final String mText_attraction_type;
    private final String mText_attraction_cost;
    
    public AttractionsItem(int img1,int img2, String text_attraction_name, String text_attraction_type, String text_attraction_cost)
    {
        mImg_1 = img1;
        mImg_2 = img2;
        mText_attraction_name = text_attraction_name;
        mText_attraction_type = text_attraction_type;
        mText_attraction_cost = text_attraction_cost;

    }
    public int getImg1()
    {
        return mImg_1;
    }
    public int getImg2()
    {
        return mImg_2;
    }
    public String get_attraction_name()
    {
        return mText_attraction_name;
    }
    public String get_attraction_type()
    {
        return mText_attraction_type;
    }
    public String get_attraction_cost()
    {
        return mText_attraction_cost;
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте в AttractionsItem какую-то переменную, по значению которой вы сможете решать какой фрагмент показать

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Вся проблема в том что я не понимаю какую переменную и как это написать, могли бы вы дать более развернутый ответ, с примером написания кода?

Comment: Сложно дать хороший ответ - не очень чёткие требования. Попробуйте вариант с добавлением int переменной. И switch потом делайте по ней, а не по position.

Comment: А можно добавить в pojo модель что то типа implements Serializeble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В класс `AttractionItem` добавляем поле `mInitialPosition`, сохраняющее начальную позицию `item`:

```
public class AttractionsItem
{
    private int mImg_1,mImg_2;
    private final String mText_attraction_name;
    private final String mText_attraction_type;
    private final String mText_attraction_cost;
    private final int mInitialPositon;
    
    public AttractionsItem(int img1,int img2, String text_attraction_name, String text_attraction_type, String text_attraction_cost, int initialPosition)
    {
        mImg_1 = img1;
        mImg_2 = img2;
        mText_attraction_name = text_attraction_name;
        mText_attraction_type = text_attraction_type;
        mText_attraction_cost = text_attraction_cost;
        mInitialPosition = initialPosition

    }

    public int getInitialPosition() {
       returt mInitialPosition;
}
...
}
```

Метод `createExampleList()` изменится:

```
    public void createExampleList() {
    exampleList = new ArrayList<>();
    exampleList.add(new AttractionsItem(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_kid, "Baby островок", "Детский", "60₽", 0));
    exampleList.add(new AttractionsItem(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_kid, "Виражи", "Детский", "80₽", 1));
    exampleList.add(new AttractionsItem(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_kid, "Вокруг света", "Детский", "50₽", 2));
    exampleList.add(new AttractionsItem(R.mipmap.unnamed, R.drawable.ic_interactive, "5D кинотеатр", "Интерактивный", "120₽", 3));
```

}

В методе `Adapter` `onBindViewHolder()` строку

```
 switch(position){
```

заменить на

```
switch(currentItem.getInitialPosition()){
```